# Expected ',' or '...' before '.' token in constructor

Tags: c++11

Having the following code:

SockAddrIn.h

```
#pragma once

#include <winsock2.h>

#include <string>


namespace networking
{
class SockAddrIn
{
public:
    SockAddrIn() {}
    SockAddrIn(const std::string& ip, uint16_t port);
    SockAddrIn(uint16_t sin_family, unsigned long s_addr, uint16_t port);
    SockAddrIn(struct sockaddr_in sin)
        : m_sin(sin)
    {}
    virtual ~SockAddrIn() {}

    operator struct sockaddr_in();
    operator struct sockaddr_in*();
    operator struct sockaddr*();

private:
    struct sockaddr_in m_sin;
};
}
```

SockAddrIn.cpp

```
#include "networking/SockAddrIn.h"

#include <winsock2.h>


using namespace networking;

SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(
   const std::string& ip,
   uint16_t port)
   : SockAddrIn(AF_INET, inet_addr(ip.c_str()), htons(port))
{}

SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(
   uint16_t sin_family,
   unsigned long s_addr,
   uint16_t port)
{
   m_sin.sin_family = sin_family;
   m_sin.sin_addr.s_addr = s_addr;
   m_sin.sin_port = port;
}

SockAddrIn::operator struct sockaddr_in()
{
   return ( m_sin );
}
SockAddrIn::operator struct sockaddr_in*()
{
   return ( &m_sin );
}
SockAddrIn::operator struct sockaddr*()
{
   return ( (struct sockaddr*)&m_sin );
}
```

The following error is generated (Line 15 is the 3rd constructor):

```
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|15|error: expected ',' or '...' before '.' token|
src\networking\SockAddrIn.cpp||In constructor 'networking::SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(const string&, uint16_t)':|
hi_client\src\networking\SockAddrIn.cpp|11|error: no matching function for call to 'networking::SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(int, long unsigned int, u_short)'|
hi_client\src\networking\SockAddrIn.cpp|11|note: candidates are:|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|16|note: networking::SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(sockaddr_in)|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|16|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|15|note: networking::SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(uint16_t, long unsigned int)|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|15|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|14|note: networking::SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(const string&, uint16_t)|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|14|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|13|note: networking::SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn()|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|13|note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|10|note: constexpr networking::SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(const networking::SockAddrIn&)|
include\networking\SockAddrIn.h|10|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided|
src\networking\SockAddrIn.cpp|16|error: expected ',' or '...' before '.' token|
src\networking\SockAddrIn.cpp||In constructor 'networking::SockAddrIn::SockAddrIn(uint16_t, long unsigned int)':|
src\networking\SockAddrIn.cpp|20|error: request for member 'S_addr' in 'S_un', which is of non-class type 'long unsigned int'|
src\networking\SockAddrIn.cpp|21|error: 'port' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

It looks like something about the 'unsigned long' part irritates the compiler.. Couldn't find anything on the web. This looks really weird to me.. What am I missing?

Comment: Add `#include <cstdint>` at the top of the file. You need it for `uint16_t `.

Comment: @RSahu Doesn't seem like it helps .. I have many, many classes with the uintx_t kind of typing and no cstdint included in them, no errors generated.

Comment: Nevertheless, give it a shot. It can't hurt.

Comment: @RSahu I did, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s_addr` is defined as a macro in `winsock2.h` (or a header `inaddr.h` included by `winsock2.h`, to be precise). Like this:

```
#define s_addr  S_un.S_addr /* can be used for most tcp & ip code */
```

This turns your constructor declaration into nonsense:

```
SockAddrIn(uint16_t sin_family, unsigned long s_addr, uint16_t port);
// becomes
SockAddrIn(uint16_t sin_family, unsigned long S_un.S_addr, uint16_t port);
```